# ExtJS 4 Panel Grid using JsonStore is not loading the grid

Tags: json, extjs

I am using ExtJS 4.0.7 and I am using JSON Store to load it to the Panel Grid. I am using Firefox version 16.0.2. It is very simple example, I am able to run Array grids.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {


var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'users',
    fields: [ 'id', 'name', 'email' ],
    autoLoad: true,
    data: { users: [ 
      { "id": 1, "name":"John Smith", "email":"jsmith@example.com"},
      { "id": 2, "name":"Anna Smith", "email":"asmith@example.com"},
      { "id": 3, "name":"Peter Smith", "email":"psmith@example.com"},
      { "id": 4, "name":"Tom Smith", "email":"tsmith@example.com"},
      { "id": 5, "name":"Andy Smith", "email":"asmith@example.com"},
      { "id": 6, "name":"Nick Smith", "email":"nsmith@example.com"}
    ]}
  });   


 var Grid1Grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
      store: Grid1Store,
      renderTo: 'grid-example',
      title: 'Target',
      width: 300,
    columns: [
      {
        id: 'name',
        header: "Name",
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'name'
      },{
        id: 'email',
        header: "Email",
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'email'
      }
    ]

});

});
```

Grid is loading and no data is displayed. It is showing a blank grid. I am not sure about the issue. Is it due to some browser compatibility issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. If you want to get useful answers, it's probably best to be more specific about what you want to know. "please check if something is wrong" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your store is local. Do not use **root** attribute

```
var Grid1Store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  fields: [ 'id', 'name', 'email' ],
  autoLoad: true,
  data: [ 
    { "id": 1, "name":"John Smith", "email":"jsmith@example.com"},
    { "id": 2, "name":"Anna Smith", "email":"asmith@example.com"},
    { "id": 3, "name":"Peter Smith", "email":"psmith@example.com"},
    { "id": 4, "name":"Tom Smith", "email":"tsmith@example.com"},
    { "id": 5, "name":"Andy Smith", "email":"asmith@example.com"},
    { "id": 6, "name":"Nick Smith", "email":"nsmith@example.com"}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Could you give me code snippet to load it from a file like sample.json OR remote call?

Comment: You should look grid examples of sencha. 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/array-grid.html